# "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError" when writing single CSV on S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I'm facing the error above when trying to write a single CSV file from my on-prem Spark cluster to a S3 bucket.

Here's my code:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .appName('my-app') \
    .config("spark.driver.host", my_host_ip) \
    .config("spark.driver.port", "12345") \
    .config("spark.network.timeout", 10000000) \
    .config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", 10000000) \
    .config("spark.storage.blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs", 10000000) \
    .config("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 2000) \
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "100g") \
    .config("spark.cores.max", str(processador)) \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", f'{str(mem)}g') \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", f'{str(mem)}g') \
    .config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC") \
    .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Duser.timezone=GMT") \
    .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Duser.timezone=GMT") \
    .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true") \
    .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true") \
    .getOrCreate()
            
spark.sparkContext.setSystemProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")

spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key', 'my-key')
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key', 'the-secret')

# creating a DF with 2 reg
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'val-col-1'), (2, 'val-col-2')], ['col1', 'col2'])

# writing on bucket
df.repartition(1).write \
    .save(path=f's3a://folder1/folder2/csv_output/', mode='overwrite', format='csv', header=True)
```

Here's the things I tried:

1. Persist on my machine (it worked);
2. Change hadoop version (and the dependencies as well);
3. (Because my tests are running on windows): add and delete "[winutils](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils)" and "hadoop.dll";
4. Reading instead of writing;

Here's the jars and versions:

- **Spark version = 3.0.1**
- **Hadoop version = 2.7.4**
- jets3t-0.9.0
- aws-java-sdk-1.7.4
- hadoop-aws-2.7.4
- hadoop-client-2.7.4
- hadoop-common-2.7.4

Here's the stack of the error:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 35.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 35)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:977)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirAccess(DiskChecker.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AOutputStream.<init>(S3AOutputStream.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CsvOutputWriter.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

In the end, is there even possible to write a single CSV from Spark (pyspark) to S3 and it is substantially faster than using a traditional approach (boto3, technically)?

Did I misunderstood anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also tried with Spark v. 3.1.2 and Hadoop v. 3.2.

Comment: and used the following cfg: 
`spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")`

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: @OneCricketeer 1.8.0_311

Comment: IIRC, Spark 3 should ideally be using Java 11. The error seems version related, though

Answer (score 0):

1. use a consistent set of hadoop 3.2 JARs
2. looks like one of the native DLLs isn't on PATH, or of a different version.
3. set `fs.s3a.fast.upload.buffer` to `bytebuffer`

action #3 will dodge the problem until you do something like try and use an s3a committer; #2 is where you need to put some effort in

the libraries you need will be on https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils

Comment: any suggestions on #2? the dlls are the same that came from the [apache dist](https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.0.1/)

Comment: sorry, not tried to get things working there for ages